# Семь или семеро сыновей?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

Нужно сказать о том, что у кого-то было 7 сыновей. Вот только встал вопрос: "у него было семь сыновей" или "семеро сыновей"? Если обратиться к классике, то тут мы видим оба варианта, например: "У старинушки три сына...", либо наоборот - поговорка "семеро по лавкам" или: "Двое. Мальчик... и мальчик".
В чем вообще разница между числительными "семь" и "семеро" (или любое другое число) и в какой ситуации как правильнее говорить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да, в вашем случае оба варианта допустимы.
Вряд ли мы скажем "семеро профессоров" или "семеро учителей" и т.п., а в остальном это синонимы, если обозначают лиц.

Answer (score 2):

Употребление собирательных числительных действительно ограниченно - не только грамматически, но и стилистически. Однако современные исследователи отмечают,  что числительные этого разряда неуместны только в официально-деловом стиле речи и при обозначении существительными мужского рода ***престижных должностей, званий, чинов, профессии***. При этом и в подобных сочетаниях указанные числительные возможны в контекстах констатирующего характера (***"Сайт представляет пятерых поэтов начала века") и в непринужденной речи, когда говорящий непринужденно рассуждает о событиях собственной жизни ("Вчера были вызваны ко мне трое генералов").*** Ибо их основное значение (обозначать количество предметов, животных, людей, которые представлены группой или действуют совместно, находятся вместе где-либо или переживают вместе какое-либо состояние) в таких случаях оказывается более существенным, нежели стилистическая окраска. 
***( Грамма.ру).***

Answer (score 1):

"Было у тёщи семеро зятьев" (русская народная песня).
А отчего нельзя сказать "семеро профессоров"?

Comment: >А отчего нельзя сказать "семеро профессоров"?

Действительно интересно. Присоединяюсь к вопросу.

Comment: Ну, наверное, потому что числительные количественные просто обозначают количество, а собирательные обозначают несколько предметов как единое целое.Представьте себе группу из СЕМЕРЫХ профессоров как единое целое. Большинство ( я в том числе) считает, что каждый профессор - это индивидуальность, самодостаточный учёный со своей школой, учениками, взглядами, менталитетом и т.д.Собирательное числительное обобщает, нивелирует, даже отчасти упрощает этот образ. Поэтому сказать-то можно, но вряд ли кто - то встретит семерых учёных в жизни (они даже внешне должны быть отчасти похожи). Вот как-то так...